# 400 error in API post request(python, requests). How to set correct parameters?

Tags: python, api, python-requests, http-post

I'm trying to load a list of leftovers using the Wildberries marketplace API using Python 3.10.

```
import requests
url = 'https://suppliers-api.wildberries.ru/api/v3/stocks/{warehouse}'
key = 'my_key'
headers_auth = {'Authorization': key}
wh_id = my_id #int
auth = requests.post(url.format(warehouse = wh_id), headers = headers_auth)
print(auth)
leftovers = auth.json()
print(leftovers)
```

I am getting the following message:
`<Response [400]> {'code': 'IncorrectRequestBody', 'message': 'Некорректное тело запроса'}`
Message translation is 'incorrect request body'

What did I do wrong?

You can see it in docs, but i'll point it here. There are no query parameters. 'warehouse' is only required  path parameter.
There are also mentioned REQUEST BODY SCHEMA, but not pointed it's 'required' to send some extra data.

Documentation is here:
[https://openapi.wb.ru/#tag/Marketplace-Ostatki/paths/~1api~1v3~1stocks~1%7Bwarehouse%7D/post](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

I also tried:
1)to write wh_id in path:

```
url = 'https://suppliers-api.wildberries.ru/api/v3/stocks/wh_id
auth = requests.post(url, headers = headers_auth)
```

2)send warehouse in data, changing with different variants of url:

```
data = {'warehouse':wh_id}
auth = requests.post(url, data = data, headers = headers_auth)
```

3)send array of barcodes like in REQUEST BODY SCHEMA

```
barcodes = ['barcode']   
data = {"skus": barcodes}
auth = requests.post(url.format(warehouse = wh_id), data=data, headers = headers_auth)
```

At first i am expecting the 200 response code.

Comment: the api expecting a json, you can try either(or both) 1. add `content-type=application/json` header.  2. `requests.post(......, json={})`

Comment: @lex thank you for the answer.  
1.I replaced my `headers_auth = {'Authorization': key}` 
to your `headers_auth = {'Authorization': key, 'content-type' : 'application/json'}`
no changes
2. I am actually don't get the point. So i tried something like that:
`json = {'warehouse' : my_id}
auth = requests.post(url, headers = headers_auth, json=json)`
I tried a both, separately and together, to no avail.
I also tried, though it seemed meaningless: 
`auth = requests.post(url.format(warehouse = wh_id), headers = headers_auth, json = {})` with different headers

Comment: I'm not sure if you can post an empty json to get all inventories(as you've tried). the API wants json so you need to post with `json=....` instead of `data=...`. does it work if you post with skus info as shown in your last line(just replace `data=` with `json=`)? `content-type` may be unnecessary if you post with `json=...`

Comment: @lex Thank you! 
`headers_auth = {'Authorization': key}
barcodes = ['barcode']   
data = {"skus": barcodes}
auth = requests.post(url.format(warehouse = wh_id), json = data, headers = headers_auth)` works well. How can i point your answer as right one?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for @lex.

It was necessery to use request body scheme and send data by json. The final version of working code is:

```
import requests
url = 'https://suppliers-api.wildberries.ru/api/v3/stocks/{warehouse}'
key = 'my_key'
headers_auth = {'Authorization': key}
barcodes = ['barcode']   
data = {"skus": barcodes}
wh_id = my_id #int
auth = requests.post(url.format(warehouse = wh_id), json=data, headers = headers_auth)
print(auth)
leftovers = auth.json()
print(leftovers)
```

The big question is whether there some way to get a list of all barcodes using this method.
And a critical moment is i realized that's not the method i need for my task. Maybe it will be helpful for someone who will work with the Wildberries API.

The right method is here: [https://openapi.wb.ru/#tag/Statistika/paths/~1api~1v1~1supplier~1stocks/get](https://openapi.wb.ru/#tag/Statistika/paths/%7E1api%7E1v1%7E1supplier%7E1stocks/get)

First is for your own stock, second for marketplace stocks. I have no leftovers in my warehouse, so although i get the 200 response, the list was empty.